# Display text rivz ROS

Tags: python, text, visualization, ros, markers

I'm trying to display text in rviz. I have used [visualization_msgs/Marker](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html) TEXT_VIEW_FACING type, but in this case text always appears oriented correctly to the view. However I would like to display text in the same way as LINE_STRIP does, without dynamic orientation regard to the view.

I have thought in convert each character into LINE_STRIP (i.e. x,y,z spatial figure) but I would have to develop a template for each character.

Is there any tool that makes this for me? Or is there any other way to address this? Thank you in advance